# Why we use floating point numbers in OpenCV?

Tags: image, opencv, floating-point

I know the `cv::8UC1` or `cv::8UC3`  formats for images, those are 1-channel 0-255 unsigned char or 3-channel for RGB 0-255 unsigned char image formats to store respectively.

But what about floating point formats like `cv::32F`? I have two questions about these guys.

1-Why they are 32-bit? I mean why we need to store intensity of a pixel in range of 0-4294967296 ? (Then I think we must convert it again to 8-bit numbers in 0-255 range!)

2-As I know we use a 2-dimensional matrix to store an image that has an integer coordinates(x,y). But I saw in some codes they use floating point numbers to find a pixel's location/coordinates. Like this part of O'reilly's book:

> Subpixel  corners
> If    you are processing  images  for the purpose of  extracting  geometric
> measurements, as  opposed to  extracting  features    for recognition,    then    you will
> normally  need    more    resolution  than    the simple  pixel   values  supplied    by
> cv::goodFeaturesToTrack()
> . Another way of  saying  this    is  that    such    pixels
>
> come  with    integer coordinates whereas we  sometimes   require real-valued
> coordinates   —   for example,    a   pixel   location    of  (8.25,  117.16).

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Your thinking about very simple images, and very simple maths. I don't have time to write an answer but checkout [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/83562/why-pixels-can-have-float-values/)

Comment: 1 reason is that you apply math formulas to the image (e.g. gradient) which generates float images which gives values that means nothing colorwise, but has more sense mathwise. For the location of the pixels is almost the same thing... it is to have more accurate results, not the same to add 8.25 to 8.25 and round it (17) that to have 8 + 8 which gives 16....

Comment: @GPPK *You're. Sorry but I can't stomach that here on SO.

Comment: @zindarod i'd update but i totally can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to make a short explanation, but I'm sure you'll get to understand it better with time anyhow.
When we capture an image in a digital way, we actually use a table-like sensor where we measure the amount of light that hits this cell. Light is a physical quantity. the fact that you limit the measured values to 0..255 does not mean that our eye is not capable of seeing more delicate division. Therefore many applications indeed give values of 0...2^16-1 instead of 0...2^8-1 (which is 255). Now, I think you know enough for answering your question :

1. Imagine I have an image of a farm taken from an airplane. I know that there is a farmer somewhere in this picture. I want to store in each pixel the probability that this pixel is the farmer (people are very small when shot from an airplane). probability ranges from 0 to 1. therefore I need floating point numbers. If I do a high precision calculation, I might need not only a 32-bit floating point but rather a 64-bit floating point for gaining more precision.
2. As mentioned above, we capture only a "table of pixels" but we assume that the reality is more complex. As it indeed is. So the farmer might "fall in" between two pixels. so, we can take a different approach: try to find the Tractor upon which the farmer is traveling, and take the middle of it. Which can fairly fall between two pixels.

Read on, with practice you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Thank you Shmuel, But as I understood, the difference is only one pixel! I mean either you do all your calculations with 32 or even 64 bit variables or only a simple 8-bit variable, the difference in result is about one pixel error? And considering millions of pixels in new monitors, maybe that is not worth it to do 32 or 64 bit calculations?

Comment: You're welcome, Hasani. 1. You're thinking about presenting images. Think about capturing & processing images. For example, there are applications that examine electric circuits and look for errors. The image is never presented on screen. just captured and processed. 2. Sometimes, half-pixel makes a difference...  think about medical applications.